# Can you get true MIN MAX of date/time from MySQL concatenated strings?

Tags: mysql

Can you get the **true** MIN/MAX of a date/time using this on MySQL?

```
MAX(CONCAT(`Date`, ' ', `Time`))
```

Considering this is a string?

I want to do this for the reason that I am working with a database where the date field and the time field is separated.

I tried doing this and it seems fine however I am wondering if there is a better way to do this that would not require separate queries.

EDIT:

Date and Time fields are in native MySQL format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date and time parts are already in the native MySQL format YYYY-mm-dd and hh:mm:ss, you can [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the concatenated result to a `DATETIME`, after which normal `DATETIME` collation will apply.

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' ', TIME(NOW())) AS DATETIME);

+---------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()), ' ', TIME(NOW())) AS DATETIME) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2011-11-06 10:42:42                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I think cast will do. However is there other way around this besides from concatenating. I think concatenated fields used in a min/max query will be slow.

Comment: @AivanMonceller It should be possible to add the two using built-in date functions, but I can't get it to work correctly with `ADDTIME()` in my testing. I agree, the `CONCAT()` may be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `addtime()`.

```
select addtime(cast('2010-11-23' as datetime), cast('48:00:12' as time));
```

If your columns are already of type `date` and `time`, this even simplifies it.

```
create table a (d date, t time);
insert into a values ('2011-11-06', '17:46:25'), ('2011-11-06', '26:12:34');
select addtime(d, t) from a;
```

You could even wrap your table in a view which combines the two fields, and then use that view.

```
create view b as select addtime(d, t) as dt from a;
select dt from b;
```